# extract data from JSON string with LINQ request

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

I have data in a JSON string with the following organization (To give you an example, I have formatted one line)

```
[
   {
    "id": 60237,
    "categories": [
       { "name": "name1" },
       { "name": "name2" }]
   }
]
```

i use following classes:

```
Public Class Entry
   Public Property Id As Integer
   Public Property Categories As Category()
End Class

Public Class Category
   Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

I have deserialised using JSON.NET

```
Dim entries() As Entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Entry())(JSONSTRING)
```

would like to extract from the JSON string, with LINQ request, data from “categories” field with a list of defined categories names. 
For example, I would like to extract each "line" of data which categories names are "name1" and "name2". The list could be under the following form: dim desiredcategories = {"name1","Name2"}

note: The name of categories are not defined by me and can change. But, Name1 and Name2 stay the same even if others categories changes or are added or deleted.

Could you help me to write the “where” line into the following request in VB .NET ?

```
Dim requestanswer = From entry In entries
                    Where ???
```

note: to simplify the post, I have not put others elements which are inside the JSON string and other classes and others "where" lines which are made into the same request.

Comment: "Extracting" data from JSON is usually done by Deserializing it.  use JSON.NET not Linq.  It can also be done via Parsing, but you already have classes.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: _I would like to extract ... data from “categories” field with a list of defined categories_ - if you want all defined categories - you don't need `Where` at all. `allCategories = entries.SelectMany(e => e.Categories).Select(c => c.Name);`

Comment: Your `Category` class only has the name, no values? What do you expect to be returned?

Comment: Note for nothing but all the comments you got on **[your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47875728/1070452)** apply to this one.

Comment: It looks like your issue is 100% about LINQ and 0% about json. Please include only relevant stuff, people are not here to read half pages of text that then prove irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your desired category names in a list:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.Add("name1")
list.Add("name2")
```

Then you can use the following code to do filtering based on desired categories:

```
Dim entries as new List(of Entry)

Dim entry1 as new Entry()
entry1.Id = 60237

Dim category1 as new Category()
category1.Name = "name1"
Dim category2 as new Category()
category2.Name = "name2"

Dim c as new List(of Category)

c.Add(category1)
c.Add(category2)

entry1.Categories = c.ToArray()

entries.Add(entry1)

Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.Add("name1")
list.Add("name2")

Dim requestanswer =(From entry In entries Where(From category In entry.Categories Where list.Contains(category.Name)).Count() > 0 select entry).ToList()

for each ra as Entry in requestanswer
    Console.WriteLine(ra.id)
next
```